# Karate gatling name resolver not working properly for GET call

Tags: karate

My name resolver isn't working for some reason.
I want to group all the calls together as a single entity in results but the result is showing it as separate call.

Issue in having them separately is I am having 500,000 such request and when gatling tries to generate report its giving heap dump memory issues.

Below is my feature file

```
Given path '/hometown/process?requestId='+__gatling.ID+'&includeSystemComments=true'
And header karate-name = 'Request History'
When method GET
Then status 200
```

I've also used

```
val protocol = karateProtocol("/hometown/process?requestId={requestID}&includeSystemComments=true" -> Nil)
protocol.nameResolver = (req, ctx) => req.getHeader("karate-name")
```

Still in the results I am getting all of them as separate Rest calls.

I wanted these calls in results to be grouped as single entity.
Below is what I have the results as: [image]

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Did you use the protocol in the inject like this? this was my issue and after fixing it, it worked.
setUp(
    getCall.inject(
      nothingFor(4 seconds),
      constantUsersPerSec(1).during(10.seconds),
...    ).protocols(protocol)
  )

Comment: Hi @LuisMauricio: Yes indeed, I missed to add the protocol at the end. Mt bad . Thankyou for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you don't even need a name resolver. Just try this:

```
val protocol = karateProtocol(
  "/hometown/process" -> Nil
)
```

Or also try without anything, e.g. `val protocol = karateProtocol()`.

Else maybe there's some other call that is "escaping". No one will be able to tell from your question, so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: NameResolvers are useful when you don't want the url to be the differentiator. The name can be used to differenciate same urls with different purposes.